# Reorder Pipe separated fields with modifications

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed, regular-expression

I have a Linux text file around 8k lines in the following format

```
|f_name:x|l_name:x|address:x x|city:x|state:x|zip:x|country:x|ordernumber:x|code:x|downloaded:x|exp:09/2017|ip:x.x.x.x|
```

And I would like to sort it to be in the following format:

```
ordernumber:x,exp:09/2017,code:x,f_name:x,l_name:x,address:x x,city:x,state:x,zip:x,country:x,ip:x.x.x.x
```

**NOTE**

Some data in the text having issue with the field of `|address:x x|`

it can be like `|address:x x |` which means there's a `space` before the ending `|`; I would like to remove the space or spaces in the output.

And there's data having issue with the field of `|exp:09/2017|`; there's data displayed like `|exp:9/2017|` so I would like to add `0` in case the month is a single number so it would be `09/2017` in the output.

Note that the year can be different.

**Example:**

```
|f_name:x|l_name:x|address:x x |city:x|state:x|zip:x|country:x|ordernumber:x|code:x|downloaded:x|exp:9/2017|ip:x.x.x.x|
```

**Expected Output:**

```
ordernumber:x,exp:09/2017,code:x,f_name:x,l_name:x,address:x x,city:x,state:x,zip:x,country:x,ip:x.x.x.x**
```

Comment: Show the code that you have tried so far.  You will get much better answers if you show that you have made an effort and you are not just asking for free consulting.

Comment: @John1024 to be honest, i were only trying to handle that through `notepad++` and I would like to learn how to handle it through Linux, on the other side i keep read about awk and sed. even so am trying now.

Comment: Hint: start with `awk -v OFS=, -F'|' '{print $9, $12 ...}'`  Can you fill in the ellipsis?

Comment: @Wildcard yea i got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU **`awk`** solution:

```
awk '{ 
         split($12, a, /[/:]/); 
         if (length(a[2]) == 1) $12=sprintf("%s:%02d/%d", a[1], a[2], a[3]);
         sub(/ *$/, "", $4);
         print $9, $12, $10, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $13 
     }' FS='|' OFS=',' file
```

The output:

```
ordernumber:x,exp:09/2017,code:x,f_name:x,l_name:x,address:x x,city:x,state:x,zip:x,country:x,ip:x.x.x.x
```

Comment: Thanks for king of  `awk,sed,regex` :D:D:D:D

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη, you're welcome. Glad to help

Comment: could you please explain for me this part `sub(/ *$/, "", $4);` this mean to remove any spaces in end of `$4` about the `address` ? are I'm correct ? if yes, which part on sub mean remove any spaces in end of $4

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη, yes, this pattern `/ *$/` matches space(s) in unlimited manner `*` at the end of the string `$` (where the input string is the 4th field `$4`)

Comment: was trying with `sub(/$* *$/, "", $0);` which mean to remove all space(s) before and after string `$` for all records. but seems something wrong :( what's wrong with my edit ? `AWK WIKI` Say `A special case, $0, refers to the entire record`

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη, this `/*$ *$/` is incorrect pattern. Use `gsub(/^ *| *$/,"")`

Comment: i edited code with `gsub(/^ *| *$/,"");` and tested it on same example but it's will remove everything and print `,,,,,,,,,,` but if i changed the `|` with `:` it's will print the line correctly but space(s) still there.

Comment: so i will use this on the output `sed 's/\s*,\s*/,/g'` to not tired you more

Answer (score 2):

### Summary

I wrote a an Awk script, a Python script, and a Bash script, each of which should solve your problem. They all produce identical output.

Here is the example data (taken from your question and put in the file `data.csv`):

```
|f_name:x|l_name:x|address:x x|city:x|state:x|zip:x|country:x|ordernumber:x|code:x|downloaded:x|exp:09/2017|ip:x.x.x.x|
```

And here is the output on running the scripts:

```
ordernumber:x,exp:09/2017,code:x,f_name:x,l_name:x,address:x x,city:x,state:x,zip:x,country:x,ip:x.x.x.x
```

### Awk

Here is an `awk` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env awk
# transformcsv.awk

# Set the input field-separator (FS) and the output field-separator (OFS)
BEGIN{
    FS="|";
    OFS=",";
}

# Skip empty lines
/^\s*$/ {next;}

# Print lines with the fields reordered as desired
{
   print $9,$12,$10,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$13
}
```

And here is how you would run it:

```bsh
awk -f transformcsv.awk data.csv
```

You could also run this as a one-liner:

```bsh
awk 'BEGIN{FS="|";OFS=",";}/^\s*$/ {next;}{print $9,$12,$10,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$13}' data.csv
```

### Python

Here is the Python script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: ascii -*-
"""transformcsv.py"""

import sys
import csv

# Make a list with the field names in their input order
# NOTE: We padding colums because each row begins
#       and ends with the delimiter `|`
fieldnames = (
    "padding_1",
    "f_name", "l_name", "address", "city", "state", "zip",
    "country", "ordernumber", "code", "downloaded", "exp", "ip",
    "padding_2"
)

# Make a list with the field names in their output order
reordered_fieldnames = (
    "ordernumber", "exp", "code", "f_name", "l_name",
    "address", "city", "state", "zip", "country", "ip"
)

# Read each input row and print out the reordered row
with open(sys.argv[1]) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter='|')
    for row in reader:
        print(','.join([row[field] for field in reordered_fieldnames]))
```

Here is how you would run the script:

```bsh
python transformcsv.py data.csv
```

### Bash

**NOTE:** This will probably be *very* slow on large files. You probably shouldn't use this - I only included it for fun.

Here is the Bash shell-script:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# transformcsv.sh

while read LINE; do
    if [[ -n "${LINE}" ]]; then

    # Extract the field values
    f_name="$(echo "${LINE}" | cut -d'|' -f2)"
    l_name="$(echo "${LINE}" | cut -d'|' -f3)"
    address="$(echo "${LINE}" | cut -d'|' -f4)"
    city="$(echo "${LINE}" | cut -d'|' -f5)"
    state="$(echo "${LINE}" | cut -d'|' -f6)"
    zip="$(echo "${LINE}" | cut -d'|' -f7)"
    country="$(echo "${LINE}" | cut -d'|' -f8)"
    ordernumber="$(echo "${LINE}" | cut -d'|' -f9)"
    code="$(echo "${LINE}" | cut -d'|' -f10)"
    downloaded="$(echo "${LINE}" | cut -d'|' -f11)"
    exp="$(echo "${LINE}" | cut -d'|' -f12)"
    ip="$(echo "${LINE}" | cut -d'|' -f13)"

    # Output the reordered row
    printf \
        "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n" \
        "${ordernumber}" "${exp}" "${code}" "${f_name}" "${l_name}" \
        "${address}" "${city}" "${state}" "${zip}" "${country}" "${ip}"

    fi
done < "$1"
```

And here is how you would run it:

```bsh
bash transformcsv.sh data.csv
```

Comment: Oh dear, the shell variant is going to be slow, you're forking subshells and invoking `cut` a dozen times for each input line! You could use `while IFS='|' read -r a b c d ...` to do it all in the shell, which would probably be usable (though the shell is a bit slow compared to e.g. awk in any case). There's some discussion of that here: [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/170373)

Comment: Besides, you shouldn't use `printf "$somevar,$othervar\n"` but `printf "%s,%s\n" "$somevar" "$othervar"` instead. Just consider what happens if some of the variables contains a `%`. And this goes for any language actually, not just the shell.

Comment: @ilkkachu Thank you for the comment. The `bash` script was just for fun. I added a warning and reordered the scripts to put it last.

Comment: @igal good morning igal, thank you very much but still just 2 points which i already explained in my question. in case if the `exp:9/2017` so i would like to add `0` if the month is single number so i need it to be `exp:09/2017`

Comment: @igal and the second point is, in case if the address for example `|address:102 test st |` so i would like to remove the end space so the output will be `address:102 test st` which means no space in the end.